# Click a Internet Explorer Link/Button with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I try to click a link on a wlan captive portal with a powershell script.
The issue is, the method can't be found and i get the following error.

Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'click'.

The relevant section of my script:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($url)

Do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
} while ($ie.Busy)

$button = $ie.document.getElementsByClassName('dtag-button btn btn-dark btn-block center-block btn-start')
$button.Click()
```

I also tried the Submit() method, but get also the same error.
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Submit'.

The source code of the website respectively the relevant section:

```
<div class="button-wrapper module-content">
<a class="dtag-button btn btn-dark btn-block center-block btn-start" role="button" href="https://www.hotspot.de/" target="_blank" transloco="welcome.button.startSurfing">Start surfing</a>
<!----></div>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does not return a single element: it returns a collection. You need to consider what should happen if _multiple_ elements match the CSS class-names you're specifying.

Comment: Also, an `<a>` is not a `<button>`.

Comment: That's why i write a link, it only looks like a button and the role is button. The output of $button seems to be correct, it is only one item.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, not a `HTMLElement`. You need to use PowerShell's collection-indexer to reference that single object. (I'm guessing you're a former jQuery user who is used to being able to use `$('etc').doStuff`-style methods to perform batch invocations of instance methods?)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the problem

```
$button = $ie.document.getElementsByClassName('dtag-button btn btn-dark btn-block center-block btn-start') | where-object {$_.role -eq 'button'}
```

Many thanks to Dai for the hint!